# Retrieve the highest value in a one-to-many-relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a loan table and a properties table. One to many relationship. If the loan contains more than one property, I have to only retrieve the property that has the highest appraisal value.

The following query

```
SELECT l.loan_id,p_count
FROM loans lo
JOIN
  (SELECT loan_id, MAX(appraised_value) AS val
          COUNT(property_id) AS p_count
   FROM properties
   GROUP BY loan_id) AS pc ON pc.loan_id = lo.id
```

gives me the output

```
loan_id val      p_count
817     914,000  2
```

But if I attempt to retrieve additional attributes (e.g type, address) from the properties table, I get records all the properties for that loan (2, in this case). I wrote this query

```
SELECT l.loan_id,p_count
FROM loans lo
JOIN
  (SELECT loan_id, MAX(appraised_value), type, address AS val
          COUNT(property_id) AS p_count
   FROM properties
   GROUP BY loan_id) AS pc ON pc.loan_id = lo.id
```

to get the following output:

```
loan_id val      p_count  type     address
817     800,000  2        duplex   123 main street
817     914,000  2        triplex  234 cedar avenue
```

How can I get the following output for the highest appraised value?

```
loan_id  val      p_count  type      address
817      914,000  2        triplex   234 cedar avenue
```

Comment: `SELECT loan_id, MAX(appraised_value), type, address AS val
          COUNT(property_id) AS p_count
   FROM properties
   GROUP BY loan_id` this subquery not gives you error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window functions to calculate the count of properties per loan and the highest value in the same query:

```
SELECT lo.id, pc.p_count, pc.appraised_value, pc.type, pc.address
FROM loans lo
JOIN (
  SELECT loan_id, 
         appraised_value,
         type,
         address,
         count(*) over (partition by loan_id) AS p_count,
         dense_rank() over (partition by loan_id order by appraised_value desc) as rnk
   FROM properties
) AS pc ON pc.loan_id = lo.id and rnk = 1;
```

As Josh commented, if two properties have the same highest appraised_value, both will be listed. If you don't want that, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`.

Comment: Your output fields do not match the desired output.

Comment: This query will also return multiple rows where two properties have the same appraised_value.  Might be okay depending on requirements.

Comment: `dense_rank` did the trick. Accepted and voted up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to rank the records:

```
select
   x.loan_id
  ,x.val
  ,x.p_count
  ,x.type
  ,x.address
from (
  select
     l.loan_id
    ,p.appraised_value as val
    ,p.type
    ,p.address
    ,row_number() over (partition by l.loan_id order by p.appraised_value desc) as ranker
    ,count(1) over (partition by l.loan_id) as p_count
  from loans l

  left join properties p
    on l.loan_id = p.loan_id
) x
where x.ranker = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
proc sql;
select a.loan_id,p1.val,p1.p_count,p2.type,p2.address
from
loans l
left join
(select loan_id,max(appraised_value) as val,count(propoerty_id) as p_count
from propoerties
group by loan_id) p1
on l.id = p1.loan_id
left join
propoerties p2
on p1.loan_id = p2.loan_id and p1.val=p2.appraised_value;
```

Let me know in case you have any different requirement.